# How to start page numbering from page 2 or 3?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

This is my code:

```
<fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
  <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="20pt" margin-right="0.5cm">
    <fo:page-number/></fo:block>
</fo:static-content>
```

There is only one sequence of slides, but I want to start numbering from number one but from slide 2 or slide 3. Can somenone help me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate `fo:simple-page-master` for the first page that does not have a `fo:region-after` and use an `fo:page-sequence-master` to specify the special `fo:simple-page-master` for the first page and then uses the regular `fo:simple-page-master` for the rest of your slides. E.g.:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first">
        <fo:region-body margin="36pt" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest">
        <fo:region-body margin="36pt" />
        <fo:region-after extent="36pt" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="psm">
      <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="first" />
      <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" />
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="psm">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
    <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="20pt" margin-right="0.5cm">
      <fo:page-number/>
    </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

---

For an unnumbered first slide and a second slide numbered '1', put the first slide in a separate `fo:page-sequence`:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first">
        <fo:region-body margin="36pt" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest">
        <fo:region-body margin="36pt" />
        <fo:region-after extent="36pt" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="first" force-page-count="no-force">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>Title slide</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="rest" initial-page-number="1">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
    <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="20pt" margin-right="0.5cm">
      <fo:page-number/>
    </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>Slide 1</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Which, if the presence of the page number is the only difference, could be simplified to:

```
<fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm">
        <fo:region-body margin="36pt" />
        <fo:region-after extent="36pt" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm" force-page-count="no-force">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>Title slide</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm" initial-page-number="1">
  <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
    <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="20pt" margin-right="0.5cm">
      <fo:page-number/>
    </fo:block>
    </fo:static-content>
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block>Slide 1</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: It works, but there is small problem. On slide 2 I have number of page 2. I want number 1 there. Is there way how to solve it? I try to set initial value to 0, but it doesn't wokrs.

Comment: Updated. '0' doesn't work because "If a non-positive or non-integer value is provided, the value will be rounded to the nearest integer value greater than or equal to 1." (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#initial-page-number)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a simple-page-master for the first page, and one for the subsequent pages. In the page-sequence-master, specify which page position should use which page-master

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="chapter">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page_first" page-position="first"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page_even" odd-or-even="even"/>
        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="page_odd" odd-or-even="odd"/>
    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

In the simple-page-master for the first page, use a region-name other than "xsl-region-after" for the region-after, so the static-content block named "xsl-region-after" will not be drawn on the first page.

Comment: I do this, but now I have number 2 on first slide. I want to have nothing on first slide and number one on second slide.