# Current page number as a number variable in XSL-FO

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

So I know that I output current page number with `<fo:page-number/>` but I need to be able to do some basic math operations with this number. I need to output for example `'page-number' - 1`. It seems simple but I tried many things and nothing worked.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You can't get the page number to use in an expression. Can you explain why you need one less than the current page number? We may be able to think of something that you could do instead to achieve the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to start page numbering from lest say page 4, starting from 1, but first pages also need to be numbered. It should be like: Page1 - 1; Page2 -2; Page3 - 3; Page4 - 1; Page5 - 2. Something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799286/how-to-start-page-numbering-from-page-2-or-3) but with first pages also numbered. I tried your answer and my pages are in different page-sequence and I added initial-page-number="1" but page 4 is still numbered as 4.

Comment: Nevermind somehow I made it work, thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm glad that you got it to work.

Comment: Consider writing a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to explain (as briefly or as detailed as you prefer) how you made it, so that in the future other people with the same problem could benefit from your experience.